# if distance between two elements is less than X do Y

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

I'm trying to calculate the distance between a website footer and a sidebar (which has a variable margin-top property as it's mimicking a fixed position element.)

In smaller resolutions, the sidebar will scroll on top of the footer. To solve this, I want to hide the sidebar when it's X px from the footer and then show it again once it's scrolled X px above the footer.

I've tried the below code (which is inside a window scroll function) but this is returning a negative number & isn't working as expected.

```
        distance = sidebar.offset().top - footer.offset().top;

        console.log(distance);

        if ( distance > -500) {
            sidebar.fadeOut('fast');
        } else {
            sidebar.fadeIn('fast');
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
//changed order, now you won't get negative number
distance = (footer.offset().top - footer.outerHeight() ) - sidebar.offset().top;

if( distance <= 50 ) // 50 or any distance you want
 sidebar.fadeOut(500);
else
 sidebar.fadeIn(500);

});
```

Added that part inside `$(window).scroll()` so that it'll be checked every time you scroll.

Comment: That appears to work, but it looks as if it's calculating the distance from the bottom of the footer, rather than the top. Should offset not start from the top of an element?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but if that's the problem, I'll edit the answer to fix that problem (by subtracting the height of footer).